# Managing multiple games with Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiplayer, socket.io-1.0, online-game

I am a newbie in node.js and socket.io. So I made a small project and tested some things with a small real-time chat, which works very nice. But I ask me, what's the best way to manage multiple games with node.js and socket.io?

Let's say, I want to create a website with some simple multiplayer card games. Each game should be a window with its own chat/room, a list of the players and a history for the game updates.

Is it better to set up all functions of each game in one big `server.js` file or run each game on its own process on the server (`game1.js`, `game2.js`...)?

Comment: The question is way too broad to be answered. But you would store the states of each match of a game, in a database. And differentiate between the matches using a session or match id.

Comment: Agree with the above comment by @t.niese, if suitable you could manage multiple games from one server but ideally you would have the logic separated in different files.

Comment: @LiamMacDonald yes, thats exactly what i asking for. I know, that i store all data of each game in my database, thats no problem. What i mean is where to write the game logic. So for example i have a "server.js" wich is the main script for all games. If i start an individual game, then my main script is loading a seperate "game logic script" only for that game to call all functions for that game. Thats what i ask for :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look at some good game networking frameworks like **GameSparks**, **Photon** etc to see how they work. Even if you want to make your own server-side code using NodeJS and SocktIO (which I think they are very suitable for your project), the frameworks I mentioned could give you some good clues about how to achieve your objective.

### Game Networking

The most used architecture in game market for multiplayer gaming is one central server, often called **master server**, which is responsible for *matchmaking*, that is, matching players who want to play together in **game rooms**.

Once **master server** had matched players, it spawns a new dedicated service to handle all game logic, which is often called **game server**.

Making a multiplayer online game is not that simple, once you need to deal with problems like *desynch*, *reconciliation*, *lag compensation* among others. It all depends on your game type/genre. I think a simple card game will not involve much of that, but those are great study topics.

You can see more details about those terms in documentations like [Valve's Source Game Networking](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) and [this article](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-server-game-architecture.html) from Gabriel Gambetta.

Comment: Yes, i understand what you mean, but it does not really answer my question. I'm more interested in being independent. I'm just wondering how I can make the game logic for each game style clearer than writing every function in one script.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in this case would be to store the game data in a database, and use an authentication method (like cookies/JWT) to know what data to serve to which player at any time. This design pattern allows for much less overhead because the game's logic is completely disconnected from the game's data, which means it can easily scale, and if a crash or a disconnection occurs, nothing is lost. It also removes the dependency to individual connections.